# AWS Stepfunction, ValidationException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions, dynamodb-queries

i got the error "The provided key element does not match the schema", while getting data from AWS dynamoDB using stepfunction.

**stepfunction Defination**

```js
{
  "Comment": "This is your state machine",
  "StartAt": "Choice",
  "States": {
    "Choice": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.data.Type",
          "StringEquals": "GET",
          "Next": "DynamoDB GetItem"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.data.Type",
          "StringEquals": "PUT",
          "Next": "DynamoDB PutItem"
        }
      ]
    },
    "DynamoDB GetItem": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:getItem",
      "Parameters": {
        "TableName": "KeshavDev",
        "Key": {
          "Email": {
            "S": "$.Email"
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    },
    "DynamoDB PutItem": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:putItem",
      "Parameters": {
        "TableName": "KeshavDev",
        "Item": {
          "City": {
            "S.$": "$.City"
          },
          "Email": {
            "S.$": "$.Email"
          },
          "Address": {
            "S.$": "$.Address"
          }
        }
      },
      "InputPath": "$.data",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

**Input**

```js
{
  "data": {
    "Type": "GET",
     "Email": "demo@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

**Error**

> {   "resourceType": "dynamodb",   "resource": "getItem",   "error":
> "DynamoDB.AmazonDynamoDBException",   "cause": "The provided key
> element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status
> Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID:
> a78c3d7a-ca3f-4483-b986-1735201d4ef2; Proxy: null)" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some potential issues with the `getItem` task when compared to [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ddb.html).

- I think the `Key` field needs to be `S.$` similar to what you have in your `putItem` task.
- There is no `ResultPath` attribute to tell the state machine where to put the results.
- Your path may not be correct, try `$.data.Email`

```json
    "DynamoDB GetItem": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:getItem",
      "Parameters": {
        "TableName": "KeshavDev",
        "Key": {
          "Email": {
            "S.$": "$.data.Email"
          }
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.DynamoDB",
      "End": true
    },
```

To be honest, I'm not sure if one of all of these are contributing to the validation error those are some things to experiment with.

On another note, there are some open source [validators](https://github.com/ChristopheBougere/asl-validator) for Amazon State Language but for this case, they were not very helpful and said that your code was valid.

Comment: Error is still comming, $.data.Email is right

Comment: Hi its working now, by adding both key in step function definition. dynamodb have two key. 1) primary partition key 2) primary sort key.  and your mentioned steps is also right.

Answer (score 0):

its working, above [JD D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1806763/jd-d) mentoned steps and also by adding both key in step function definition.
DynamoDb have two key.

1. primary partition key
2. primary sort key